# How to modify the cells in a column in R

Tags: r, dataset, cell, rstudio, kaggle

I am working on a dataset from Kaggle and here's some parts of the data set

[image]

So I would like to delete the time in the "Date" column, which would only show "15-05-13" instead of "15-05-13 17:00". I was wondering how to code this?

I think it should be something like this:

```
train$Dates <- sub("15-05-13 17:00", "15-05-13", train$Dates)
```

But in this way, it's going to take me forever because the data set is huge...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wendy, all you need is:

```
train$date <- format(as.Date(train$date,'%y-%m-%d'),'%y-%m-%d’)

> train
      date
1 15-05-13
2 15-05-13
3 15-05-13
```

Answer (score 2):

I split the Dates column into two, using " " as a separator

```
train <- data.frame(date = c("15-05-13 17:00", "15-05-13 16:00", "15-05-13 15:00"))
train
#             date
# 1 15-05-13 17:00
# 2 15-05-13 16:00
# 3 15-05-13 15:00

train <- data.frame(date=c("15-05-13 17:00", "15-05-13 16:00", "15-05-13 15:00"))
within(train, date<-data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(date), ' ', fixed=TRUE))))
train
#    date.X1 date.X2
# 1 15-05-13   17:00
# 2 15-05-13   16:00
# 3 15-05-13   15:00
```

and dropped the time column

```
train$time <- NULL
```

Now if you call train:

```
#    date.X1 
# 1 15-05-13 
# 2 15-05-13 
# 3 15-05-13
```